# scheduleWithFixedDelay only running when calling get() method

Tags: java, concurrency

I am creating a ScheduledExecutorService with the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService schedExe = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

I am calling this thus:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> sf = schedExe.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RequestScheduler(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The RequestScheduler() class, for testing purposes is a simple implementation of Runnable thus:

```
public class RequestScheduler implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    System.out.println("$$$$RequestScheduler running");

}
 }
```

When I call scheduleWithFixedDelay no code is run.  If I refrence the get() method of the ScheduledFuture returned by the call it runs.
**Any idea why this might be happening? Should I need to call get() on my ScheduledExecutorService?** 
The creation of the ScheduledExecutorService is in a local method (it was at the class level before but I moved it).  This is the complete method that is called from main:

```
    public void pollDatabase(long databasePoll, String tbHost, int tbPort, int maxPool) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException{

    if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
        logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format(Messages.CREATED_SCHEDULER, new Date().toString(),databasePoll,maxPool,tbHost,tbPort) );
    }
    ScheduledExecutorService schedExe = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledFuture<?> sf = schedExe.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new RequestScheduler(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        System.out.println(sf.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("-call to executor has been made");
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. This is just a test runnable the real one runs a load of queries and makes http calls.  I would presume that there is no "need" to call get, hence the question, but it is, sadly, the only way I can get it to run.  I will investigate further.